# I've read an Auger recipe but I still can't craft one. Why?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I've learned the recipe but it does not show up. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. According to the wiki:

> You can craft the Auger by clicking on any of the parts in your inventory and selecting "assemble". From there you can put your parts into the spots and craft the Auger.

I tried it with a `Small Engine` and I was given the option to construct an Auger or a Chainsaw.

Comment: I tried it with a hunting rifle. It worked.

Comment: That's pretty cool that you can build an auger out of a hunting rifle ;)

Answer (score 0):

Schematics are not always unlocking receipts for Forge\Workbench, i.e. guns schematics.

Auger has recipe in Workbench for Handle Bars and Auger Blade, but to craft Blade (upgrade actually) you need to have one at first. So having Blade and Part you almost guaranteed to have Auger. Small Engines are pretty common, and Handlebars you can craft yourself.
Same for Chainsaw.